# Need help to run my swing graphics code

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw moon-like shapes(or maybe any arbitary shape achieved with my code) at the positions where the user clicks on the JFrame.
But i'm getting runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.<init>(AffineTransform.java:488)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.clone(SunGraphics2D.java:267)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.create(SunGraphics2D.java:300)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1000)
at Shapes$component.paintComponent(Shapes.java:48)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at Shapes$component.paintComponent(Shapes.java:48)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at Shapes$component.paintComponent(Shapes.java:48)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at Shapes$component.paintComponent(Shapes.java:48)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at Shapes$component.paintComponent(Shapes.java:48)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at Shapes$component.paintComponent(Shapes.java:48)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
```

Where am i wrong?How to remove this error.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Shapes extends JFrame{
private ArrayList shapes=new ArrayList();
    Shapes()
{
super("Creating moon on mouse clicks");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(400,400);

addMouseListener(new listener());
add(new component());
setVisible(true);
}
public class listener extends MouseAdapter
{
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    int x=e.getX();
    int y=e.getY();
    int rand=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
    int temp;
    Area a1=new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,rand,rand));
    temp=(int)rand/3;
    Area a2=new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(x+temp,y+temp,temp,temp));
    a1.subtract(a2);
    shapes.add(a1);
    repaint();
}
}
public class component extends JComponent
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++)
    {
        g2.draw((Shape) shapes.get(i));
    }
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Shapes();}});
}

}
```

Comment: The most recent mistake you've made was neglecting to include the error stack trace in your question.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share their reasoning?  This question is expressed more clearly than most.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you override `paintComponent()` you are calling `super.paint()` instead of `super.paintComponent()`.

Default implementation of `JComponent.paint()` executes `paintComponent()`, `paintBorder()` and  `paintChildren()`. So, executing `super.paint()` from `paintComponent()` creates endless execution loop. That is the reason for `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Damn!! what a stupid mistake and i was swimming through the code for past half  hour to find the error.
Thanx Max and MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    // ...
}
```

Just in case you missed it ;) - It should read

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // ...
}
```